# Display dispatch date in minicart Magento2

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

how to show the dispatch date on the mini cart after adding the item the items? can anyone help me out with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail about where the dispatch date information will come from?

Comment: it will come form the Checkout/Helper/data.php

Comment: i make the dispatchdate function on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the below code to achieve your desired result.

Folder structure will be as below

[image]

Create **app/code/Tarun/CustomizedMinicart/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Tarun_CustomizedMinicart" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Create **app/code/Tarun/CustomizedMinicart/registration.php**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Tarun_CustomizedMinicart', __DIR__);
```

Create **app/code/Tarun/CustomizedMinicart/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem">
        <plugin name="appendData" type="Tarun\CustomizedMinicart\Plugin\DefaultItemPlugin" sortOrder="10" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Create **app/code/Tarun/CustomizedMinicart/Plugin/DefaultItemPlugin.php**

```
<?php


namespace Tarun\CustomizedMinicart\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;

class DefaultItemPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param AbstractItem $subject
     * @param array $result
     * @param Item $item
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterGetItemData(AbstractItem $subject, array $result, Item $item): array
    {
        $dispatchDate = "03-01-1989"; //Set your date here from helper as mentioned by you in your comment
        $result['dispatch_date'] = $dispatchDate;
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Create **app/code/Tarun/CustomizedMinicart/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="itemRenderer" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
                                    <item name="simple" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
                                    <item name="virtual" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="item.renderer" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/cart-item-renderer</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Tarun_CustomizedMinicart/minicart/item/default</item> <!--Changed the template path here from Magento's to Custom-->
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="item.image" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/js/view/image</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/product/image</item>
                                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">itemImage</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create **app/code/Tarun/CustomizedMinicart/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html**

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<li class="item product product-item" data-role="product-item">
    <div class="product">
        <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
            <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
        <span class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
            <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="product-item-details">
            <strong class="product-item-name">
                <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: $parent.getProductNameUnsanitizedHtml(product_name)"></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                <span data-bind="html: $parent.getProductNameUnsanitizedHtml(product_name)"></span>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko if: dispatch_date -->
                <span data-bind="text: dispatch_date"></span>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </strong>

            <!-- ko if: options.length -->
            <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
                <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                <div data-role="content" class="content">
                    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                    <dl class="product options list">
                        <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                        <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                        <dd class="values">
                            <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                            <span data-bind="html: $parents[1].getOptionValueUnsanitizedHtml(option.value.join('<br>'))"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && ['file', 'html'].includes(option.option_type)) -->
                            <span data-bind="html: $parents[1].getOptionValueUnsanitizedHtml(option.value)"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && !['file', 'html'].includes(option.option_type)) -->
                            <span data-bind="text: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </dd>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <div class="product-item-pricing">
                <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->

                <div class="details-map">
                    <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                    <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->

                <div class="details-qty qty">
                    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>
                    <input data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           'data-item-qty': qty,
                           'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                           }, value: qty"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           class="item-qty cart-item-qty"/>
                    <button data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           title: $t('Update')
                           }"
                            class="update-cart-item"
                            style="display: none">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product actions">
                <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
                <div class="primary">
                    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                       class="action delete">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message notice" if="$data.message">
        <div data-bind="text: $data.message"></div>
    </div>
</li>
```

**Just for your information :- I have copied the above template from vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html and added below three lines**

```
<!-- ko if: dispatch_date -->
    <span data-bind="text: dispatch_date"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

[image]

**If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.**

**Happy Coding**